# Similarity of real-valued functions

Tags: real-analysis

The concept of similarity is well defined for $n\times n$ matrices. Two $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ are called similar if there exists an invertible $n\times n$ matrix $P$ such that $$B=P^{-1}AP. \quad (1)$$

In addition, $A$ and $B$ share many proprieties.

I was wondering if there is an analogous definition for real-valued functions $f$ and $g$ that are connected by a similar expression like $(1)$ (even if it happens in a specific field). It means, there is a invertible function $\phi$ such that $$f=\phi^{-1} \circ g \circ \phi.$$

Comment: Yes. It's generally referred to as [Topological conjugacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_conjugacy) and is of tremendous importance in the study of discrete dynamics. The relation $\varphi\circ f = g\circ\varphi$ can also be used when $\varphi$ is not invertible.